# Quadratic Residues in $\mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I was playing around with quadratic residues in $3^n$ modulo systems and am now wondering if there is a neat closed form solution for the set of all quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z} $ for any n.

A couple minutes of fiddling and it's easy to prove that all numbers of the form 3x+1 are residues.

However, I'm not seeing anything immediately in the remaining residues congruent to 0 mod 3.
Haven't found anything on this particularly simple case anyway on the internet.

Every other power of 3 is congruent to 1 mod 8, so perhaps there's not a good solution...?

Comment: i.e. if $y = 1$ mod $ 3$ then there exists $x$ such that $x^2 = y $ mod $ 3^n$.
if $y = 2$ mod $3$, it's a non residue.
what about the 3rd case?

Comment: There is no third case. By the usual definition a QR of $m$ is an $a$ relatively prime to $m$ such that the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$ has a solution.

Comment: yes sorry that is bad wording. but there is still a set of $a$ such that $x^2 - a = 0$ has roots.  and this is the set i was asking about.

Comment: For $1\lt a\lt 3^n$, need $a=3^{2e}(3k+1)$.

Comment: By the way, why is it that the definition of quadratic residue omits the case of $a$ being relatively prime with $m$? can you motivate this for me?

Comment: It omits the case of $a$ **not** being relatively prime to $n$. It all started with odd primes, where it is nice to have just as many QR as NR, and the case $a=0$ is dull. For more general $m$, we are working in the (multiplicative) group of units.

Comment: aagh sorry very tired and inaccurate, NOT relatively prime, yes.  actually i'm seeing that quite a few sources don't restrict the definition to those numbers that are relatively prime with the modulus.

Comment: If it's Wikipedia it means nothing.

Comment: wolfram too, though skepticism perhaps due there as well

Comment: In all the textbooks I have used in teaching number theory, QR has meant in particular relatively prime to $m$. I have never seen it used another way in a book, but can only be sure about textbooks.

Comment: Ok, good to know! Ireland and Rosen, which is what I've been using, definitely agrees with you.

Comment: however, some ocw notes from MIT conform oppositely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group has two components, one which is the number of powers of $3$ that are in your number, and one that is the unital translate thereof, because **all** (non-zero) integers have a **unique** representation of the form $3^j\cdot m$ with $\gcd(m,3)=1$, and so

$$\Bbb Z/3^n\Bbb Z\cong RU$$

with

$$\begin{cases}R=\{ 3^k:0\le k\le n\}\\ U=(\Bbb Z/3^n\Bbb Z)^\times\end{cases}$$

this is not a group product, as the group operation is addition, but is a representation via products of numbers (which is sufficient for talking about residues). So first you ask if the power of $3$ involved is even or $n$, if not:  no dice, if so proceed to step 2. Step 2:  is the unital component a square in $(\Bbb Z/3^n\Bbb Z)^\times$? If so:  yes, if so and $3^n\not\equiv 0$, then no.

We can even deal with the units explicitly:  $(\Bbb Z/3^n\Bbb Z)^\times$ is a cyclic group, and so you need the unique subgroup of index $2$ of squares within it. However, everything projects down to either $1$ or $-1\mod 3$ in this group, so and this is a homomorphism from $U\to\{\pm 1\}=(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^\times$, which is non-trivial, hence its kernel, namely everything which is $1\mod 3$ is exactly equal the group of unital squares.

So we know that all squares modulo $3^n$ are numbers of the form

$$\begin{cases}m=3^{2k}(3k+1) & 0\le 2k\le n\\ m & 3^n|m\end{cases}.$$

Comment: So then the full set of $a$ such that $x^2-a = 0$ mod $3^n$ has a root is just $ {\{ 3^{2k} \cdot (3y+1) \ \ \  |  \ \ \ \ 0 \leq y < 3^{n-1}, 0 \leq 2k < n }\}$
?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to my answer to make it clear. Well, that and $0$, and you mean a weak inequality.

Comment: oh yep definitely that.
thanks for the clear exposition, nicely put all.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone endeavoring to learn more number theory like me, I found this to be a very helpful article related to the above question.
http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Walter_D22068._Stangl.pdf

Comment: I think you've made a mistake. Your [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2531695/revisions) on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531695/probability-and-statistics-about-computer-chips-manufacturing-and-coast-reductio) post doesn't really make sense. Why did you remove the percentages?

Comment: yep that's my bad, mathjax was having some rendering trouble and i didn't sanity check the output to see that it made any sense.  It didn't.  I should be fine now.  

p.s. this is a very silly place to leave this comment.